# Error message displayed on all my forms

Tags: php, html, web

I have three forms on my page, one for update personal details(Names) Second one for update password and last one for updates user devices.

When user clicks on submit for a certain form maybe for change password, the message is display on all the forms that password is successfully changed. I want the message to be displayed on that form that was updated.

The code

My submit buttons

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Update Password" name="changepassword" style="margin-left:70px;"/>

 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Update" name="updatepersonal"/>
```

My php

```
global $errorstr;

    if (isset($_POST['changepassword'])) {
        $oldpassword = $_POST['currentpassword'];
        $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
        $confirmpassword = $_POST['repassword'];

        if ($newpassword != $confirmpassword) {
            $errorstr = "New passwords do not match";
        }
        else {
            changepassword($oldpassword, $newpassword);
            if ($errorstr == "") {
                $errorstr = "Password changed successfully";
            }
        }
    } else if (isset($_POST['updatepersonal'])) {
        $newfirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
        $newlastname = $_POST['lastname'];      

        changename($newfirstname, $newlastname);
        if ($errorstr == "") {
            $errorstr = "Name changed successfully";
```

My error message is on each form.

```
<?php if ($errorstr != ""){ echo "<div class=\"warn\">$errorstr</div>";}?>
```

Comment: all inputs have the same id (id="submit"), ID means identifier and they should be unique

Comment: I changed them with different names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can identify that form using post method like

```
if(isset($_POST['changepassword'])) {
 echo "your message";

}
```

SAME FOR OTHERS

Comment: This is what I'm doing currently,

 if (isset($_POST['changepassword'])) {
  $oldpassword = $_POST['currentpassword'];
  $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
  $confirmpassword = $_POST['confipassword'];

Comment: But the message after making changes, is displayed on all forms.

Comment: can you paste code 
are you passing message while submitting form if yes then what is the field name of that so i can improve answer properly

Comment: please give full code to get proper ans in question

Answer (score 0):

when you click on submit button it will reload the page. and according to your back-end process it will load new page. either you can you ajax call you submit a data and display a message or you can show thrown back-end that you must be knowing that the page redirected and updated certain information and pass that data to redirecting page

```
$("input[name='changepassword']").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
url:url,
type: 'POST',
data:form.serialize(),

            success:function (result) {
              Show Messages here
}});
});
```